# After Saving Configurable Product I cannot Upload Parent Image

Tags: magento2, image

I create a configurable product and add in all the variations and their individual photos and then save. 
I come back to add the main photo for the configurable product. All the simple products have their photos associated with them.
It uploads the image but when I try to save it. It looks as thought it is saved but it does not save the image. If I click back into the product, there is no parent image. 
It's a fresh install using Magento blank as a theme. I've cleared the cache etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just read that this issue might have more to an update needed to my server. It appears that all configurable products cannot be updated upon edit. It is not just being unable to add a photo but I cannot change attributes etc.

[Magento 2 admin - can no longer save configurable products after upgrade to 2.1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125394/magento-2-admin-can-no-longer-save-configurable-products-after-upgrade-to-2-1/126847#126847)

Going to try this suggestion and hope it works as my POSTs are also being blocked and I am getting 404s.
They updated the apache mod_security that was apparently blocking the POST action to the URL.